# Sort NSArray of NSDictionaries ignore case

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I am sorting an NSArray of NSDictionaries which is working using the following code

```
NSArray *getIndexArray = [nicknamesCombinedArray copy];

            NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"MANUFACTURER"  ascending:YES];
            NSDictionary *sortedGetIndexArray = [getIndexArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

The only issue is that when it sorts if the word is all CAPS then it sorts like this

```
JESS
Jack
Jelly
Job
```

Where I would like it to be

```
Jack
Jelly
JESS
Job
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code..

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"MANUFACTURER"  ascending:YES  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```